# datatables cannot read property of undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i am getting error your  cannot read property of undefined i have below is code which describe table structure there is also edit() function i am trying to store id in my id variable using var id=data[0] but my i am getting error on this line

[image]

```js
function edit() {
  var current_row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
    if (current_row.hasClass('child')) {
        current_row = current_row.prev(); 
    }
    var data = table.row(current_row).data(); 
    console.log('Row data:' + data);
    var id = data[0];
    $("#ID").val(id); // here i am getting error
}
//datatable structure
  function createCustomisedDatatable(arr) { 
 table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "data": arr,
  "iDisplayLength": 10,
  "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
  "bDestroy": true,
  responsive: true,
 columnDefs: [

    {
      responsivePriority: 1,
      targets: 1
    },

    {
      "aTargets": [0],
      "sTitle": "Id",
      "class": "Id",
      "bSortable": true
    }, {
      "aTargets": [1],
      "sTitle": "name",
      "class": "name",
      "bSortable": true
    }, {
      "aTargets": [2],
      "sTitle": "gender",
      "class": "gender",
      "bSortable": true
    }, {
      "aTargets": [3],
      "sTitle": "pincode",
      "class": "pincode",
      "bSortable": true
    }, {
      "aTargets": [4],
      "sTitle": "City",
      "class": "City",
      "bSortable": true
    }, {
      "aTargets": [5],
      "sTitle": "Action",
      "bSortable": true,

      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        var returnHTML = CreateDataHTML(data);
        return returnHTML;
      }

    }
  ],

  order: [1, 'asc']
});
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything in data variable or its just empty  ?

Comment: var data = table.row(current_row).data();

Comment: Why are using `[0]`? Looks like you are creating a single, non-list variable. Also, if `data()` is a function, I wouldn't recommend `data` as a variable.

Comment: What is the `console.log(current_row);`? if there is nothing, try to change `var current_row = $(this).parents('tr'); ` to `var current_row = $(this).parents('tr[role="row"]'); `

Comment: Please show how you call `edit()` function.

Comment: Actually, I would change $(this).parents('tr');  to $(this).closest('tr');

Comment: It looks like you are using the legacy version

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
 // returns an array for each row. Since t here is only one row, 
 // there will be only one item in the array.
 var data = table.rows(current_row).data(); 

console.log('Row data:' + data);

var rowData= data[0];
// now you need the column  that it belongs to
$("#ID").val(rowData[0]); // assuming that id is in the first column
```

Comment: That is not correct, `row().data()` returns one dimensional array.

Comment: do you have this set up in jsfiddle or some place we can see it run?

Comment: You should ask original poster for an example. However your answer is not correct, the problem is most likely elsewhere.